# warning: the function 'ord' should be called on each calculation for consistency

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to write a new strategy using RCI in Pine script, but I am getting the following warning; "The function 'ord' should be called on each calculation for consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope."
I found out that the reason of the warning is that I don't call the function "ord" every bar, but I am a beginner in Pine and I don't know how to fix the code. Here, the RCI part is copied from the built-in indicator. Could you please tell me how to solve the error?

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="RCI strategy test")

itv = input(12, "interval")
src = input(close, "source")

ord(seq, idx, itv) =>
    p = seq[idx]
    o = 1
    s = 0
    for i = 0 to itv - 1
        if p < seq[i]
            o := o + 1
        else
            if p == seq[i]
                s := s + 1
    o + (s - 1) / 2.0

d(itv) =>
    sum = 0.0
    for i = 0 to itv - 1
        sum := sum + pow((i + 1) - ord(src, i, itv), 2)
    sum

rci(itv) => (1.0 - 6.0 * d(itv) / (itv * (itv * itv - 1.0))) * 100.0

cond1 = rci(itv) <= 0
cond2 = rci(itv) > 0

if (cond1)
    strategy.order("L", strategy.long)

if (cond2)
    strategy.close_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
itv = input(12, "interval")
src = input(close, "source")

f_rci(_src, _len)=>
    _sum = 0.0
    for _i = 0 to _len -1
        _p = _src[_i]
        _o = 1
        _s = 0
        for _j = 0 to _len - 1
            if _p < _src[_j]
                _o := _o + 1
            else if _p == _src[_j]
                _s := _s + 1
        _ord = _o + (_s -1) / 2
        _sum := _sum + pow(_i + 1 - _ord, 2)
    (1 - 6 * _sum / (_len * (pow(_len,2) - 1))) * 100

rci = f_rci(src, itv)
```

Comment: Dear rumpypumpydumpy

Thank you for your prompt reply. I tried the method you showed me and it worked correctly! Thank you very much for taking time out of your busy schedule to help me! I'm new to PINE, so I will try to study and understand the code.